# Let $f(x)=1/(1−x)$. Can we represent the limit when $x \to 1$ by a divergent series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let the function $f(x)=1/(1−x)$
can we represent the limit when $x$ tends to $1$ by divergent series?

If there is an infinity of possible series, I want a series which has a [partial sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_summation) equal to $1$ in analogy with the divergent series $1+2+3+...$ which has a partial sum equal to $-1/12$

Comment: Be careful with stating $1+2+3+\ldots = -\frac{1}{12}$, unless you are understanding exactly the context of when and how this could possibly work, you are simply dead wrong. What is your level of understanding on divergent series?

Comment: You could use p-adic numbers...

Comment: @TheoutZ I understand, why 1+2+3...=-1/12 in the Casimir effect, In fact, in the physical world, energy is discrete and represents Dirac pulses. Thus, there is a summation of energy pulses which gives a finite result, even though these pulses represent an infinite sum. In other words, 1, 2, 3... represent Dirac pulses and their summation is indeed finite.
Clearly here I am looking for a divergent series that if I represent it in the form of a dirac impulse sum I find that the sum is equal to 1

Comment: The Casimir-effect has nothing to do with the "equation" $1+2+3+\cdots=-1/12$" , instead $-1/12$ is an assignment emerging from an analytic continuation.  But that does not make this "equation" valid. The sum and the value do not coincide anymore , so this equation does not hold (not even in "some sense").

Answer (score 1):

No, any representation of $\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1}{1-x}$ will be undefined. The left and right limits are $\infty$ and $-\infty$. Arithmetic with either, over the standard real numbers isn't well defined.

However, to address the divergent series aspect of your question, you could write

$$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$
And so you could evaluate the limit value

$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{1}{1-x} "=" \lim_{x\to1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \underset{x=1}{\longrightarrow} \sum_{n=0}^\infty 1^n = 1+1+\cdots $$

You could then attempt to adjoin a value to $\Bbb{R}$ that would make $\frac{1}{1-x}$ continuous at $1,$ allowing you to "plug in" $1.$ The problem is that any value you choose here would need to be consistent with multiplication and addition of real numbers, and would take on all the awful and poorly defined properties of $1/0.$

I think you ought to be careful, though, and notice that "plugging in $1$" into the power series does not give you $1/0,$ although the result is undefined for various reasons.